# ToolBar overflow menu shown in black theme when TabLayout is used

Tags: android, menu, material-design

I have a custom `ToolBar` layout. I am using that in many activities. In all activities except the ones which uses `TabLayout`, the menu is light theme. But in Tab activities, it is holo theme. How can I fix this?

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/secondaryBlue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
</style>


<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">5.0dp</item>
    <!--<item name="android:popupBackground">#FFF</item>-->
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primaryWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/primaryBlack</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTheme</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/primaryBlack</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/design_tab_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryBlack</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="StarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
    <item name="android:rating">4</item>
    <item name="android:stepSize">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dip</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below line into your theme attribute:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```